# HTML to PDF using pdf-creator-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I want to generate a pdf from html using pdf-creator-node. while generating the pdf, the header and the footer should be same in all pages but body part has to change. the pages are in A4 size. At present I am able to generate only one page pdf, when try to insert more information into body page is getting expanded, but here i want to split the page, and in next page i want to genrate differet body with same header and footer as first page.

i am generating doc

Comment: I am using pdf-creator-node is the library

Comment: table header and footer should be the same but the body contents need to be changed, if the contents are 10 then the first page is supposed to be filled with 7 the remaining 3 should be on the second page. The table in the second has to same as the first table contents need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add following Class where you want to add new page it works for me

//
`.add-new-page { page-break-before: always; }`